# Есть проблема "один лет"

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, профиль-участника

Наткнулся что в профиле у [Grundy](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/186999/grundy) написано

> Участник на протяжении 1 лет, 4 месяца

А должно быть года, я так полагаю, что такая проблема с числительными может быть не только здесь.

Comment: @alexolut да, чистый дубликат (только я не увидел этот вопрос). Но пусть решают этот вопрос. а то там стоит `cтатус-завершено`, а уже столько времени прошло.

Comment: Возможно, что когда целое число лет, то используется другая строка, и тот вариант действительно исправлен. Надо найти профиль пользователя для проверки.

Comment: @alexolut [Grundy](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/186999/grundy)

Comment: С целым числом действительно [исправлено](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/users/195803/m-tukai).

Answer (score 6):

### **[Проблема исправлена](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/289232/339911), [строки переведены](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/-1?key=e39b362eccc2425b04d9ef53ad0a9c27).**

---

С целым числом действительно [исправлено](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/195803/m-tukai):

> [image: 1 года]

Единственная подходящая полностью строка в transifex выглядит так:

> [$years$ лет, $months$ месяца](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/40267424?key=e39b362eccc2425b04d9ef53ad0a9c27%7Cmonths%3Dfew%2Cyears%3Dmany)

Но она используется для `months=few, years=many`. Т.е. явно не для случая, когда 1 год и 4 месяца.

Строка, которая **должна бы** использоваться для упомянутого в вопросе случая выглядит так (`months=few, years=one`):

> [$years$ год, $months$ месяца](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/40267425?key=e39b362eccc2425b04d9ef53ad0a9c27%7Cmonths%3Dfew%2Cyears%3Done)

Но она не используется, значит, скорее всего, принадлежит другому контексту.

Есть ещё вариант, что проблемная строка, содержащая:

> 1 лет, 4 месяца

может склеивается отдельно из "лет" и "месяца". Но таких строк в transifex для значения `years=one` [не видно](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/40267420?qt=%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%82).

Единственный вывод из этого: либо берётся не та строка (с другими числовыми вариантами), либо просто её нет в transifex.

Имхо, такой *reverse-engineering* не лучший способ докопаться до истины, поэтому надо [пинать разработчиков](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/288470/339911), чтобы однозначно выяснить как формируется исходная строка.

Comment: Так я хотел, что с этим разбирались разработчики. Надеюсь, вы не сильно много времени убили на ваши исследования.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov прежде чем пулять разрабов, надо было понять, а нельзя ли сделать без них.